# Visual Studio Setup Project and placing application in startup path

Tags: c#, setup-project, startup, registry

I've created a function that executes in the beginning of an installation to create a registry key in the SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run path, so the app can start when the computer starts.

The function works in a XP / 2003 machine but not on Windows 7. The install application Elevates the privileges during installation automatically because it is installing a windows service program. So I'm wondering what am I doing wrong again?

Here is the function:

```
private void RegisterInStartup(bool isChecked)
{
    try
    {
        string t_registeryPath = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";

        RegistryKey registryKey =
            Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(t_registeryPath, true);

        if (registryKey == null)
            registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(t_registeryPath);

        if (isChecked)
        {
            string tgt_dir = Context.Parameters["targetPath"];
            if (!Directory.Exists(tgt_dir))
                return;

            string t_exeName = Path.Combine(tgt_dir, "AppTaskbarNotificator.exe");
            if (!File.Exists(t_exeName))
                return;

            registryKey.SetValue("AppTaskbar", t_exeName);
        }
        else
        {
            registryKey.DeleteValue("AppTaskbar");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

and it is placed in the Install function which is overridden in the Installer Class of the App in mind.

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    RegisterInStartup(true);
    StartApp();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't create the registry entry when installed in windows 7.

Comment: Make sure you are reading the correct registry keys for x86 and x64 as x64 Windows 7 installations are more common.  Have you determined where your code fails at?  If not...add debugging code.

Comment: The code doesn't fail. It run through fine, (using a debugger). It just wont create a key. I tried it with CurrentUser root instead of LocalMachine, still no difference.

Comment: Look in the "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run" key.

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant, that was my problem. Even though I told it to install under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\..., it redirected it to the HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\... key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE is a per-machine location, so your custom action needs Administrator privileges to write in it. You can give it these privileges by making it [deferred with no impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Visual Studio 2010 makes custom actions deferred with no impersonation by default, but older versions don't. So you may have to edit the MSI with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the appropriate flags.

Another solution is to write your registry entry in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: Oddly enough, I use VS2010 and I still had to use Orca to deal with elevated permission during install and uninstall. The other odd this is that, putting it under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE Doesn't work on my Win7 machine, but it works for Windows 2008 R2.